# why is there an underscore and a dash in this sentence

Tags: meaning-in-context, punctuation

I am reading [this article about being single](http://www.askmen.com/dating/curtsmith_100/134_dating_advice.html), where the opening line is:

> You're single **—** a heat-seeking bachelor, committed to no one in particular, able to party like John Belushi and sleep until noon with no one underfoot to tell you to do otherwise. It's a great life, and why shouldn't it be?

Why are the underscore and dash there? And what does "heat-seeking" mean in that context?

Comment: The first is not an underscore, but an [em dash](http://www.thepunctuationguide.com/em-dash.html). The second is a hyphen, used in this case to form a compound adjective.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung cool i have never heard of this em dash

Comment: I’m sure [you will start seeing them everywhere](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Baader-Meinhof_phenomenon#Frequency_illusion). As it says in the link I provided, it is an extremely versatile bit of punctuation. Be warned, however. That versatility means that it easy to overuse it.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung if you understand that em dash could you provide me with a sum up of its use ?

Comment: It’s an attempt to imitate speech, where a thought can start and be interrupted by another with no great confusion to the listener. Some people disagree with its use, because it’s usually put in place of proper punctuation. In this case, it appears to be taking the place of a semicolon.

Comment: @TylerJamesYoung so in TOEFL test, should I use it or it is not generally approved?

Answer (score 1):

The dash after "single" is an **em dash**. See [dash](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Dash) on wikipedia.

As for **heat-seeking**, I presume it means the bachelor is solely interested in finding a "warm/hot" woman, but without any other commitment such as marriage.

Comment: Given the term’s history describing missiles, I think “heat-seeking” is potentially suggestive.

Comment: what does this em dash means in that conext pelase? the same for dash (hyphen)

Comment: @Anaksunaman: Leave *something* to the imagination! Sure, there are overtones of what you say, to those inclined to see things that way. But figurative *heat-seeking missiles* don't always have to be that clinical/erotic.

Comment: @FumbleFingers Okay, okay. Something left to imagination now. Sorry. ;-)